# Sending emails using Shoppe gem + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, actionmailer

trying to send an accepted order email notification with the Shoppe gem.

**production.rb**

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :user_name            => ENV['chbrown1293'],
      :password             => ENV['*******'],
      :authentication       => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

**orders controller**

```
  def payment
    gon.client_token = generate_client_token
    @order = Shoppe::Order.find(current_order.id)
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
        amount: current_order.total,
        payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce])
    if @result.success?
      Shoppe::OrderMailer.accepted(@order)
      current_order.destroy
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Payment successful, congratulations!"
    end
  end
```

Not sure what I'm missing but its probably quite obvious! (I've never set up a mailer before - I am indeed a noob :))

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoppe has an automatic mailer built into the app's gemfile under it's orders controller if I am not mistaken. (Check the github repo to confirm)

In order to access it you should setup the config file for production with the mailer information.

Also ensure that you setup the mailer on "/shoppe/settings"

As soon as you make a purchase you should be sent an email.

Comment: I've got a similar question to the OP, and not entirely sure what your solution entails.  I've set this is environment.rb: ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => ENV["SEND_GRID_ACCOUNT"],
  :password => ENV["SEND_GRID_PASSWORD"],
  :domain => 'mydomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
and can send emails through rails c and then Shoppe::OrderMailer.received(order).deliver_now, but I don't get any email when completing the order through the site

Comment: Can you check the server logs to see if there are any delivery errors? Can you also ensure that you have set the same email in shoppe/settings ?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Shoppe ever, but in ActionMailer, we have to call method `deliver` in order to send emails. Try changing

```
Shoppe::OrderMailer.accepted(@order)
```

to

```
Shoppe::OrderMailer.accepted(@order).deliver
```